# Populate field with drive time values during isochrone creation in Carto

Tags: postgis, postgresql, carto, sql, isochrone

I'm creating isolines (isochrones) in Carto to show 15, 30, 45, and 60 minute drive times from a set of points in a shapefile. Here is the SQL I've written to create those isochrones in an empty table. But I'd also like to populate a field with the corresponding drive time, so 15, 30, 45, or 60. Here is my SQL:

```
INSERT INTO <my_empty_table> (the_geom, point_name, latitude, longitude, drive_time) 
    SELECT (cdb_isochrone(the_geom, 'car', ARRAY[900,1800,2700,3600]::integer[], ARRAY['is_destination=true','mode_traffic=enabled','quality=1']::text[])).the_geom, 
      point_name, latitude, longitude, ??????
      FROM <my_points_table>
```

This SQL (minus my new "drive_time" field) works, because I've successfully run it. But what I'm struggling with now is what to write in place of the `??????` so that I can populate the new `drive_time` field with the corresponding drive_time that's being calculated in `ARRAY[900,1800,2700,3600].` (The isochrone array is in seconds, which is why my minutes are multiplied by seconds to get 900, 2700, etc., although for the drive_time field I'd like them to simply read 15, 30, 45, 60).

I'm thinking it's something like `XXX.drive_time`, but I'm not sure what `XXX` should be. I tried `(ARRAY[15,30,45,60]::integer[]).drive_time` but got the error: `Error in SQL query: column notation .drive_time applied to type integer[], which is not a composite type,` so I obviously do not know what I'm doing.

For reference, here are Carto's isoline functions: 
https://carto.com/developers/data-services-api/reference/#isoline-functions

Answer (score 1):

You would need to extract the_geom and distance range from the isochrone function (= data_range) and transform the seconds to minutes.

For example:

```sql
WITH isochrone_result AS (
SELECT  my_points_table.longitude, my_points_table.latitude, iso.the_geom, iso.data_range / 60 as drive_time
    FROM  (
             SELECT the_geom, ST_X(the_geom) as longitude, ST_Y(the_geom) as latitude 
              FROM my_points_table
      ) my_points_table,
        cdb_isochrone(
              my_points_table.the_geom, 
              'car', 
               ARRAY[900,1800,2700,3600]::integer[], 
               ARRAY['is_destination=true','mode_traffic=enabled','quality=1']::text[]
        ) as iso
)
INSERT INTO my_empty_table(the_geom, latitude, longitude, drive_time) 
SELECT the_geom, latitude, longitude, drive_time FROM isochrone_result
```